# BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when getting name of picked contact

Tags: android, contacts, contactscontract

I use the Contact picker to get the name of a specific contact. For Eclair and later I use:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);
```

and in `onActivityResult()` I just do:

```
final String contactName = data.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME);
```

This works fine except on Motoblur, where I get this exception:

```
android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.motorola.blur.provider.contacts.IdentityModel
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:1883)
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableArray(Parcel.java:1922)
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1825)
    at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2008)
    at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:208)
    at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1034)
    at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:3399)
```

Is there another way of getting the name which would work on Motoblur as well? Is there a workaround for Motoblur?

Thanks in advance,
Jonas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ContentResolver` works fine. It seems like `Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME` doesn't work reliably on all phones (I've also heard reports about it not working fully on HTC).